# What is a good Java library to write GPS metadata on JPEGs (in EXIF)?

Tags: java, gps, preview, google-latitude

I have developed a Java application (Latipics) that geotags pictures with location information pulled from Google Latitude. I use an open source library called Sanselan to read/write GPS coordinates from/into JPEGs' metadata.

It works mostly great except that Apple's Preview (stock JPEG viewer in OS X) seems to misinterpret the GPS longitude reference ([see issue in more details](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?p=596930#post596930)).

Anyway, I'm considering dropping Sanselan but I can't find a suitable replacement (keep in mind I need to be able to **write** into the metadata, not just extract)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm considering using Sanselan, but it looks like it hasn't had any updates in a while. Are you still using it?

Comment: It's still implemented in an older version of my app that seems to work fine. It's been a while but I think I had to fix a bug (I forgot what it was but I could probably find it). I've since open-sourced my code at https://github.com/tbertran/Latipics

Answer (score 0):

Look out for OpenGTS source code...you may get some lead for your needs!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing better than [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).  It's open source too and very reliable.  It's not written in java, but there's nothing to stop you calling it from a java program.